# What type of sentence is a list of dependent clauses

Tags: syntactic-analysis, complex-sentences

I'm trying to classify the following sentence as compound, complex or compound-complex:

> These are: a book with drawings, a man holding a picture and a statue.

I think it's a complex sentence, because I think it has an independent clause (These are) and three dependent clauses (a book with drawings, a man holding a picture, a statue).

However, the regular words that start a subordinate clause aren't there, so I'm feeling like I'm missing something.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but to me it looks like a simple sentence that just lists three things.

Comment: When the listed things are described using several words, doesn't that make them clauses?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: A clause requires a subject-verb relationship. Simply adding words to a description does not make a clause ("a car" is not a clause; neither is "a green car" or "an old green car" or "an incredibly valuable old green car." @user139454 is correct--this is a simple sentence that lists three things. More below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a complex sentence.  There are 3 kinds of sentences:  simple ones; compound ones, which have more than one independent clause; and complex ones, which include an independent clause and one or more dependent clauses.  See more at [ENGL 1001](http://www2.ivcc.edu/rambo/eng1001/sentences.htm).

This sentence contains the dependent clause "holding a picture," so it's complex.

Comment: Isn't "a man holding a picture" a clause? It has a subject (a man) and a predicate (holding a book).

Comment: Argh, you're right.  Fixed.

Comment: So it's enough to have a dependent clause, and it doesn't matter if the words that usually start a dependent clause are there?

Comment: Right.  ENGL 1001 has its definition, and I'd go with that, but it makes sense:  a sentence doesn't change because you omit some understood words.  "The reason I gave" is a noun with a modifying relative clause, even if we left out "that" ("The reason that I gave").

Comment: @nitzanms "holding a picture" is not a predicate, because "holding" does not function as a verb. It functions as an adjective (it describes which man is being referred to--the one "holding the book"). The "man holding a picture" is a participial phrase, not a clause.

Comment: Huh, okay. That is quite confusing.

Comment: Participial phrases are also known as participle clauses or participial clauses ( http://grammar.about.com/od/pq/g/partphraseterm.htm, http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv106.shtml ).  (cont'd in next comment...)

Comment: I don't see it. Participial phrases always act as adjectives. The sentence in question is a simple sentence: It includes a subject ("these") and a predicate "are a book with drawings, a man holding a picture and a statue." In other words, "these" comprises three things: a book, a man, and a statue, two of which are modified by adjectives ("with drawings," a prepositional phrase, and "holding a picture," a participial phrase). Which book? The one with drawings. Which man? The one holding the picture. Adjectives do not a complex sentence make.

Comment: From http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/clauses.htm: "A clause is a group of related words containing a subject and a verb. A clause can be usefully distinguished from a phrase, which is a group of related words that does not contain a subject-verb relationship, such as 'in the morning' or 'running down the street' or 'having grown used to this harassment.' A review of the different kinds of phrases might be helpful." In short, "Holding a picture" is this case is a phrase, not a clause. If we say "The man is holding a picture," "holding" is a verb.